# Horizontal scrollbar is missing from panel

Tags: vb.net, scroll, panel

In VB.Net (VS2012) I have a Panel with autoscroll set to true. I have labels and grids inside the panel. The vertical scroll bar shows up as soon as the program is run (because the objects don't fit vertically). However, when I shrink the form and the grids and labels no longer fit horizontally, the horizontal scroll bar never appears in the panel.

I event tried setting HorizontalScroll.Visible = True

but this didn't help.

Why would the Horizontal bar not show up when it is needed?

Comment: Do you have autoscroll set to True on the panel or the form itself? Try setting it to true on the form itself and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: It's on the panel. I don't want it on the form. That would mess up my UI.

Comment: Have you tried anchoring the panel?

Comment: Also if you can provide a simple testbed that would help..

Comment: Did panel "follow" form resize? What meant with "follow", did panel resize too with form resizing (so panel is never widther than form)? because, I just try and works fine. But panel resize too on every form resize (in width only, for this test, using, under `Form1_Resize`, code : `Panel1.Width = Me.ClientRectangle.Width - (Panel1.Left * 2)`, and `AutoScroll=True` for `panel`).

Comment: I tried anchoring it and that doesn't help. I do resize the panel when the form resizes, but the controls inside the panel do not get resized. So eventually they do not fit in the panel. That's when the panel should show scroll bars but only the vertical bar appears.

Comment: The behavior of the horizontal scroll is very odd. If I set the form so that when I minimize it down to  a certain size, the panel changes to autoscroll= false and I set horizontalscroll.visible = true, the horizontal scroll bar does show up but it doesn't work properly. It only changes the size of the srcoll bar when you move the scroll bar, not when the panel changes size. So the scroll bar remains fixed until you move it and then it suddenly adjusts itself to the correct size so you can scroll. When I expand it back to large, the H scroll stays there until I click on it, then it disappears.

Comment: It's like the horizontal scroll doesn't get updated with the resizing of the panel, but the vertical scroll works perfectly.